# which Fortran standard of these codes?

Tags: syntax, fortran, subroutine

I am confused that the syntax in the subroutine of fortran code as following:

```
subroutine X(lr_orth_response)(mesh, st, lr, omega)
  type(mesh_t),   intent(in)    :: mesh
  type(states_t), intent(in)    :: st
  type(lr_t),     intent(inout) :: lr
  R_TYPE,         intent(in)    :: omega
  
  integer :: ist, ik
  PUSH_SUB(X(lr_orth_response))
  
  do ik = st%d%kpt%start, st%d%kpt%end
    do ist = 1, st%nst
      call X(lr_orth_vector) (mesh, st, lr%X(dl_psi)(:,:, ist, ik), ist, ik, omega)
    end do
  end do
  
  POP_SUB(X(lr_orth_response))
end subroutine X(lr_orth_response)
```

I've checked all Fortran standards and I cannot find any useful info about it! Does anyone know what's the label `lr_orth_response`? Also, accessing to data by the pointer is also confused a little bit in this line `lr%X(dl_psi)(:,:, ist, ik), ist, ik, omega)`, in which `lr` is a new type `lr_t` defined by user but there is no member functions or variables named `X(dl_psi)`.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

This is not pure Fortran. It looks like a source that must be preprocessed by some preprocessor, perhaps the C preprocessor `cpp` or its variant `fpp`. The preprocessor will expand `R_TYPE`, `PUSH_SUB`, `POP_SUB` and `X` using some macro. Some of the macros apparently depend on some parameter called `lr_orth_response`. We cannot say what that parameter does in those macros without actually seeing the definition but we would need much more code from you. It is probably used for some generic programming, but hard to guess how exactly.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks! Your guess is reasonable and these codes are from computational quantum chemistry package Octopus 9.2. More specified, they are from the file states/linear_response_inc.F90, see https://gitlab.com/octopus-code/octopus/-/blob/9.2/src/states/linear_response_inc.F90.

Comment: @YingxingCheng The capital F in the extension makes it to be preprocessed by `cpp` or `fpp` automatically. However, the code is incomplete. Most likely, the file is included somewhere else using the `#include` directive. The relevant macros are then defined in that file that contains the `#include`. hose includes can be nested. The `_inc` in the file name makes it explicit that it is a file that is to be included.

Comment: You are right. The file is included in `linear_response.F90` in which some C++ macros are included to discriminate the real number and complex number used in this subroutine. Thanks again!